# Typesetting text in multiple languages without repeating the text

Tags: xetex, pdftex, tex-core

I am working on typesetting an Indian text in three languages using ITRANS + XeTeX. I have pasted an example below. How do I avoid having to repeat the text for getting three different outputs. Can I set the text to a variable (like what we do in everyday programming?)

This would make maintenance and correcting errors easier. Any tips would help!

Edited to add more information: I am using ITRANS for Xetex (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetex-itrans). Here is more of the tex file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\RequireXeTeX
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newcommand\devtext{\catcode`\^=11
\catcode`\~=11
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=itrans-dvn]{Sanskrit2003}}   

\newcommand\kantext{\catcode`\^=11
\catcode`\~=11
\fontspec[Script=Kannada,Mapping=itrans-kan]{Kedage}}

\newcommand\romtext{\catcode`\^=11
\catcode`\~=11
\fontspec[Script=Greek,Mapping=itrans-iast]{Times New Roman}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\devtext  % This will produce devanagari
devaM nArAyaNaM natvA sarvadoshhavivarjitam.h  | \\
paripUrNaM gurUMshchAn.h gItArthaM vaxyAmi leshataH  || \\
}
\bigskip
{\kantext  % This will produce kannada
devaM nArAyaNaM natvA sarvadoshhavivarjitam.h   \\
paripUrNaM gurUMshchAn.h gItArthaM vaxyAmi leshataH \\
}
\bigskip
{\romtext  % This will produce accented roman
devaM nArAyaNaM natvA sarvadoshhavivarjitam.h |   \\
paripUrNaM gurUMshchAn.h gItArthaM vaxyAmi leshataH  ||
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have identical input for the three commands and they transliterate the text?

Comment: ...so you're looking for a way to have LaTeX translate your text for you? Nah-ah. Can't have your cake *and* eat it *and* have gluten-intolerance. :)

Comment: Lol @Werner .. not really. I am doing all the transliterating, but if there was a way I can use the same input for all three languages. If you look closely, it is the same text wrapped in three commands for three languages. I get the correct output -- I am trying to refine the process now :)

Comment: `\newcommand{\KrishnaText}{your text here}` and later use `{\romtext \KrishnaText} {\kantext \KrishnaText}`. Everytime you call `\KrishnaText` LaTeX will input what you defined with `newcommand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\fontspec` in the document body; it's better to have `\newfontfamily`.

In order to avoid code duplication, it's also better to abstract the commands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\devfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=itrans-dvn]{Devanagari MT}
\newfontfamily\kanfont[Script=Kannada,Mapping=itrans-kan]{Kannada Sangam MN}
\newfontfamily\romfont[Script=Latin,Mapping=itrans-iast]{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\definetrans}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{\catcode`\^=11 \catcode`\~=11 #2}%
}
\definetrans{\devtext}{\devfont}
\definetrans{\kantext}{\kanfont}
\definetrans{\romtext}{\romfont}

\newcommand{\definetext}{%
  \begingroup\catcode`\^=11 \catcode`\~=11 \dodefinetext
}
\newcommand{\dodefinetext}[2]{%
  \endgroup\newcommand{#1}{#2}%
}

\definetext{\mytext}{%
  devaM nArAyaNaM natvA sarvadoshhavivarjitam.h  | \\
  paripUrNaM gurUMshchAn.h gItArthaM vaxyAmi leshataH  ||%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\devtext \mytext}

\bigskip

{\kantext \mytext}

\bigskip
{\romtext \mytext}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result is suboptimal for Kannada, but the font I have doesn't seem to understand the translitteration map.

Note that with a simple `\newcommand{\mytext}{...}` the settings of `^` and `~` wouldn't be applied, so I defined a command that takes care of this (`\definetext`).

Don't load `xltxtra`, unless you need its features (which is unlikely); load rather `fontspec`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Your answer has been very helpful -- I loaded different fonts (Sanskrit2003, Kedage (for Kannada)) and it worked just fine! Thank you!